# Dependent resources in a RESTful API

Tags: django, rest, architecture, django-rest-framework

For the last few days I’ve been looking into the world of REST frameworks (the Django rest framework in specific).
The concept of a RESTful API seems pretty straight forward but there is one thing I’ve been wondering about.

Let say I have the following data structure:

```
Group
ID
GroupName

User
ID
UserName

GroupUser
userId
groupId
```

When working with dependent resources I’ve been wondering how you would return and create these objects.

In the case described above I can think of two ways to create a user and add the user to one or more groups:

Option 1: 
I send a POST request with the UserName to the server. 
Followed by one or multiple POST request adding the user to one or more groups. Adding non existing groups in separate POST requests.

Or, options 2:
I create the user and add all the groups in the request and let my serialiser take care of any of the groups that have not been created yet.

The second option sounds more efficient but request can probably start looking rather strange since some of the groups will be defined by an ID (know groups) and some by a name (non-existing groups). The main thing with this solution is that the serialisers will be rather different from the models.

My question basically boils down to the following:
In a RESTful API how should you deal with dependent resources?

Answer (score 0):

It becomes pretty obvious if you try naming the things.

Option one would be something like:

```
// creating the user
POST /user

// adding users to the group
POST /usergroup
POST /usergroup

// adding a new group
POST /group
POST /usergroup
```

Option two would be more like:

```
POST /CreateUserAndGroupMappingCreatingMissingGroups
```

Option two is a RPC model, not a restful model.

REST is about nouns: if you can't name the thing you are posting to, or if that thing looks like a verb, then you haven't built a very restful service.

There is nothing wrong with a RPC service; just be aware of what you are creating.